# Help identifying an old alien movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I need help identifying an old alien / sci-fi movie. I think it was from the 80s or early 90s possibly. I remember a couple of things about the movie such as these scenes:

- The movie begins or ends with a scene where a number of bald people are trying to close a door that is on another world or on a spaceship and there is a blue light coming out of the other side.
- At one point in the movie there is an alien posing as a teacher. Someone walks in on her in an empty classroom and sees her writing weird glyphs/ symbols on a whiteboard of blackboard. Then when they confront her, her eyes go black, she opens her mouth and a weird noise is emanated.

Sorry to be vague, this is all I remember and its driving me nuts. What's worse is when I saw it, it was dubbed in Russian, so I can't even remember what the actors were talking about in the movie.

Answer (score 5):

[Something Is Out There](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096134/), (1988).  I remember the bald people at the beginning are on a prison ship, but I think they're under the mental control of the escaping xenomorph, and are trying to open the door, not close it.  I remember a possessed professor writing calculations using alien symbols on a blackboard, but it was a male professor.  His coworker/girlfriend, unaware that he has an alien inside him, is yelling at him for being emotionally distant.